# Will browsers request /favicon.ico or <link> first?

Tags: http, browser, cross-browser, favicon

I want to set a favicon to be requested from a static file server instead of the main web server for performance optimization.

If I specify a `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.site.com/favicon.ico">` but also have a `/favicon.ico` in my site root as a fallback, which will browsers prefer? Will browsers (and which?) still look for `/favicon.ico`, making the move to a static file server useless?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I did the test suggested above. I placed a /favicon.ico in the root of a domain, and a link, and fired up the page in:

1. Opera 10
2. Opera 9.64
3. Firefox 3.5
4. IE 6
5. IE 7
6. IE 8
7. Safari 4

They all showed the icon loaded with `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.site.com/favicon.ico">` (located on an external server). I checked `access.log`, and there were no requests to `/favicon.ico`!

I then commented out the `<link>`, checked again in all browsers, and they showed the `/favicon.ico` icon and corresponding entries in `access.log`.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is: the link should trump the local file on most modern browsers, but it really depends on the implementation with non-mainstream browsers (although you probably don't really care about other browsers than IE, Firefox, Safari and Chrome)

It should also be pretty simple to test this yourself. Just put the `favicon.ico` file in the site folder and also add a link to a *different-looking* icon file on the static server and then see which one is loaded in different browsers.

Comment: Thanks, I could do that test, but.. it would also include checking access logs to see if the browser maybe first made a request to favicon.ico but then decided to go with the linked version instead. Sounds unreasonable, but that only makes it more likely IE would do it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that browsers aren't the only thing that will request favicon's - many crawlers and other applications do too.