# when favicon.ico is requested?

Tags: http, favicon

When does a browser request favicon.ico? Is it after getting 200 HTTP status code? Or maybe before accessing page itself? I have no idea...

Comment: Presumably, some time during the page is rendered. Why do you want to know?

Comment: There is a lot of browsers...

Answer (score 0):

According to [Will browsers request /favicon.ico or <link> first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554620/will-browsers-request-favicon-ico-or-link-first), the  tag in the page source overrides the request to /favicon.ico, meaning it is requested after getting a response of some kind. Don't think a specific status matters much, except for redirects and others like that of course

Comment: @Sarah I know the question and responses in the link wasn't the same. But their experiments show that the browsers tested all requested the page, and parsed it before requesting favicon.ico. Meaning it is after getting a 200 HTTP status code (but pages with other status codes might also trigger a request for favicon.ico afaik)