# Request call to favicon.ico gets 404 http status with MVC 3 and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've seen many questions on SO and blogs how to configure MVC to not route request calls to favicon.ico file but no one seems to work for me. The lates blog I read was the Phil Haack http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx but I still see the calls to the favicon.ico file resulting in 404 error status code.

I know that there is many workarounds but would like to know why it just doesn't work with that delcaration :

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

which is at the begining of the route registrations.

I'm working with MVC 3, Chrome and IISExpress

What I'm missing ?

Comment: do you actually have a favicon in your app?

Comment: no, I don't. That's the issue ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `IgnoreRoute` for the favicon makes it so that .net doesn't do anything when the favicon is requested. You still need to have a `favicon.ico` file in your application in order to prevent requests from returning 404.

Google Chrome ([among other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554620/will-browsers-request-favicon-ico-or-link-first)) automatically requests the favicon every time you browse to your site so that it can display it in the tabs.

Comment: I'm getting this 404 when trying to call a Web API REST method from a handheld (Compact Framework/Windows CE app). Why would a REST method think it needs to look for/present favicon?